# Android IllegalStateException: Fragment already added (only if onConfigChanged is called at launch)

Tags: android, android-fragments

This error occurs only if I launch the app and immediately change the orientation during the launch phase.  onCreate gets called, then onResume gets called, then onConfigurationChanged gets called and I experience this error.  If I launch the app, wait a second and then change the orientation, everything works flawlessly.

Where the FragmentPagerAdapter is created.  This is in the onCreate of the main activity.

```
mAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());


viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(25); //I want those fragments to not be destroyed
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And the displayFragment is created.  This is also in the onCreate of the main activity.

```
displayFragment = new DisplayFragment();
```

In the FragmentPagerAdapter, getItemPosition(Object item) returns 0 for the displayFragment and getItem(int index) returns the reference to displayFragment for index 0.

This is the related code inside onConfigurationChanged.

```
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            this.getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .detach(displayFragment)
                    .attach(displayFragment)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            lastOrientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            //this.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            lastOrientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            //this.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            this.getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .detach(displayFragment)
                    .attach(displayFragment)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            lastOrientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
}
```

And the stack trace.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: DisplayFragment{42b66cd0 #0 id=0x7f0a0001 android:switcher:2131361793:0}
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1133)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:618)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:479)
        at android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2533)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2211)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1350)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1547)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1234)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6465)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've now tried committing each of the transactions separately, but the error still remains.

```
this.getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .detach(displayFragment)
    .commit();
this.getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .attach(displayFragment)
    .commit();
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: post all you code also the part where you add the fragment `DisplayFragment`

Comment: More context on the DisplayFragment creation. Where it happens, which method, etc.

Comment: Alright, anything else?

Comment: First, you should directly create the fragment by calling `new DisplayFragment()`. Secondly, you seem to create a new Fragment each time in your Activity's onCreate, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found something that works.  In the onConfigurationChanged if I check the isResumed state of displayFragment, I can determine if it should be detached/attached.  No more crashes if I rotate while launching.  This causes the fragment view to be recreated without recreating the entire fragment.

```
if(displayFragment.isResumed()) {
               this.getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .detach(displayFragment)
                        .attach(displayFragment)
                        .commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't `detach` and then `attach`.
Firslty because it won't have any effect (it's in the same Transaction).
Secondly, because you can simply check if the fragment is already added before adding it. (either `findFragmentByTag` will return null, or `displayFragment.isAdded()` will return the correspondingvalue).

Comment: I guess I should clarify.  I need to force that fragment to destroy and then recreate its view.  I'm primarily an iOS developer so Android is rather new to me.  This is the only way I found to cause the fragment to recreate its view without completely destroying the fragment.  Is there a better way?

Comment: So you must commit the first transaction (detach) before re-attach the fragment.

Comment: I didn't spot the correct mistake. Here you should call the `remove`/`add` methods

Comment: If I use remove, the entire fragment is destroyed and when I call add/show, nothing displays.  Ideally I just want to inflate a different XML for the landscape layout with this particular fragment.  With my original method, the fragment isn't completely destroyed, but just its view.  Then when it is reattached, the onCreateView is called so I can inflate the proper xml.  That way works perfect except when you rotate the device as you are launching the app so idk if it's a race condition within the FragmentManager or what.

Comment: Is this Fragment added via XML or programmatically from your Activity? I can't see where it is created/added

Comment: Programmatically.  I've updated my info in the question.